# function only accepting integers?

Tags: javascript

i have a problem with this function only excepting integers, i need it to only accept strings that are valid between 2-15 characters?
any help is appreciated thanks.

```
function getDescription() {
var Description = [];
Description = prompt("Enter the description: ", "");
    while (!(Description >= 2 && Description <= 15))
    {
        Description = prompt("Error! The description must be between (2 - 15) characters in length.\nEnter the description: ", "");
    }
return Description;
}

getDescription()
```

edit: I think the other problem i am experiencing is what i am inputting is it actually getting stored as an array in Description?

Comment: There's more to detecting an integer than restricting the length of its string representation ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of the `prompt` function is a string, so you need to check the length of that string, not the value of it:

```
while (!(Description.length >= 2 && Description.length <= 15)){
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `.length`. **[Light reading material.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)**

Answer (score 2):

Use `length` property:

```
while (!(Description.length >= 2 && Description.length <= 15))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, but what exactly is length doing? i thought length outputs the length of what is stored in your array?

Comment: @user1265535 you initialize the variable to an empty array, but then you assign to it the return value from the `prompt()` call. After that point, it won't be an array anymore - it'll be a string.

Comment: can i make my arrays global and parse them through the functions?

Comment: Strings are array-like structures (collections) of characters. You can't do everything you could do to an array with a string but you can reference characters in a string with array-notation and .length is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression that will match that the user entered between 2 and 15 digits:

```
function getDescription() {
    var description = prompt("Enter the description: ", "");
    if (description.test(/^\d{2,15}$/)) {
        return description;    
    }
    else {
        return getDescription();    
    }
}

getDescription()​;​
```

Comment: Not that it's a big deal in an unlooped operation but I suspect that's a bit heavier than just doing a couple a comparisons on .length

Comment: I thought that he wanted to accept only between 2 and 15 digits, not just any random characters. Apparently I was wrong.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I missed the '\d'. I could see why you would think that. The q wording was a little vague.

Comment: The confusion comes from the first sentence of the OP where he makes 2 completely contradictory statements: at the beginning he talks about integers and then strings. Confusion often arises from a poorly expressed requirement.